# I want to save MergingmediaSource into file

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to save MerginMedia source in internal file .
In exo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Cad.png)player how can i do this.

```
  MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource
           .Factory(new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this))
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+"Aaaaaaa/a/video.mp4"));
    MediaSource audioSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this))
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+"Aaaaaaa/a/audio.m4a"));

    MergingMediaSource mergedSource1111 = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, audioSource);
```

I want to save mergedSource1111  in internal memory please helps.